# CloudFormation Nested Stacks: Unable to find parameters from parameter store for this account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm facing an issue parsing SSM parameters from a root stack into a child stack. When creating the stack, the first stack resource fails with "
Unable to fetch parameters [value1,value2,value3,value4] from parameter store for this account."

However, the value of the parameters is fetched. The values are strings too, which are supported by CloudFormation. Also, when using the same template on independent stacks, the stacks are deployed as intended. The values of the parameters in SSM are like this: **subnet1,subnet2** hence the need to split the values afterwards during ALB creation.

Below are the stacks.

root template

```
Parameters:
  PublicSubnetAZ:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: 'PublicSubnetAZ'
    Description: "Public Subnet AZs"
  AppSubnetAZ:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: 'AppSubnetAZ'
    Description: "App Subnet AZs"
Resources:
  LBStack:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: "https://s3bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/load_balancing.yaml"
      Parameters:
        PublicSubnetAZ: !Ref PublicSubnetAZ
        AppSubnetAZ: !Ref AppSubnetAZ
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-lb"
```

nested template

```
Parameters:
  PublicSubnetAZ:
    Type: String
  AppSubnetAZ:
    Type: String

Resources:
    LoadBalancerExternal:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
        Properties:
            Name: !Join ['-', [!Ref AWS::StackName, "external"]]
            Scheme: "internet-facing"
            Type: "application"
            Subnets:
              - !Select [0, !Split [',', !Ref PublicSubnetAZ]]
              - !Select [1, !Split [',', !Ref PublicSubnetAZ]]
            SecurityGroups:
              - '{{resolve:ssm:ExternalLoadBalancerSecurityGroup}}'
            IpAddressType: "ipv4"
    LoadBalancerInternal:
      Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer"
      Properties:
        Name: !Join ['-', [!Ref AWS::StackName, "internal"]]
        Scheme: "internal"
        Type: "application"
        Subnets:
          - !Select [0, !Split [',', !Ref AppSubnetAZ]]
          - !Select [1, !Split [',', !Ref AppSubnetAZ]]
        SecurityGroups:
          - '{{resolve:ssm:/InternalLoadBalancerSecurityGroup}}'
        IpAddressType: "ipv4"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you exactly using the ssm in the root stock? What is the full error message? What are the input parameters for the template?

Comment: I'm using the SSM parameter in the root stack in the parameters section, as shown in the snippet. The full error message is stated in the explanation. The input parameters are in the default section.